# Нахождение корня функции методом деления отрезка пополам.Но есть случай когда программа не работает

Tags: c++, c, численные-методы

Если ввести функцию `sin(x)*50*M_PI` и `а=313 b=316`,то программа не работает, что я сделал не так и что необходимо еще добавить?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int sign(double x)
{
    if (x>0)  return 1;
    if (x<0)  return -1;
    return 0;
}
int funkciya=0;

double f( double x)
{
    ++funkciya;
    return sin(x)*50*M_PI;
}
double root_half(double a, double b, double (*f)(double), double eps)
{
    double c,fa=f(a),fb=f(b),fc; int number = 0;
    if( fabs(fa)<eps ){ printf("Number of iterations: 1\n"); return a;}
    if( fabs(fb)<eps ) { printf("Number of iterations: 1\n"); return b;}
    if(sign(fa) == sign(fb)) {printf("Method does not run\n");return 0;}
    for(;fabs(b-a)>=eps; number++)
    {
        c=(a+b)/2;
       fc=f(c);
        if (fc == 0)
        {
            printf("Number of iterations: %d\n",number);
            return c;
        }

        if (sign(fc) == sign(fa)) { a = c; } else { b = c;}
    }

    printf("Number of iterations: %d\n",number);
    return c;
}
int main(void)
{
    double a,b;
    scanf("%le %le",&a,&b);
    printf("root = %lf\n",root_half(a,b,f,1e-15));
    printf("Function calls: %d\n",funkciya);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вообще-то надо начинать с проверки. а применим ли МПД к исходным данным. С синусом запросто можно поиметь оба заданных значения одного знака...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы слишком подняли точность - `double` с ней не справляется, и вычисление

```
c = (a+b)/2
```

дает то же значение - `c==a`. Добавьте вывод с большой точностью и убедитесь...

Не тянет представление `double` столько знаков. Дайте `eps ==` e-13`, и все получится.

Часто (но не всегда) имеет смысл задавать относительную погрешность - условие не

```
fabs(b-a) >= eps
```

а

```
fabs((b-a)/a) >= eps
```

Comment: мантисса типа double https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Число_двойной_точности 52 бита. Это значит, что **относительная** погрешность этого типа : 1/(2^52) = 2.22e-16 умножаем на 316 и получаем реальную погрешность 2.22e-16*316=7.017e-14 и вашу точность 1e-15 невозможно достичь.

Comment: @Harry я ответил так,как вы сказали,но почему-то учителю не понравился такой ответ на свой вопрос. Вопрос учителя:В чем причина того,что программа не работает?Как устранить имеющуюся ошибку?

Comment: Уменьшить требуемую абсолютную точность. От вас учитель требует вычислить корень уравнения с абсолютной точностью 1е-15? Тогда вариант - исходя из периодичности функции `sin` перевести условие в диапазон 0-2*pi, найти корень в нем, а потом вернуться в исходный диапазон. Проблема только в том, что при переходе между диапазонами точность все равно будет потеряна...

Comment: @Harry ,Кажется я понял в чем проблема,одного условия fabs(b-a) >= eps недостаточно,лучше еще добавить fabs(b-a) > eps*fabs(a+b)/2  и  тогда все работает.Спасибо вам.